# How can I add a Marker to a concrete type?

Tags: rust

I'm currently exploring Rust and am stumped by the following issue:

Let's say I want to "annotate" a function argument with a MarkerTrait (i.e. making the trait an annotation to the):

```
use std::marker::MarkerTrait;

pub trait X: MarkerTrait { }

pub trait MyInterface {
    fn foo(&self, bar: u32+ X) -> u32;
}

// make this compile in the playpen
fn main() { }
```

The compiler as of now will reject this with the following: message:

```
<anon>:6:25: 6:28 error: expected a reference to a trait [E0172]
<anon>:6     fn foo(&self, bar : u32 + X) -> u32;
                                 ^~~
```

Is this a bug or intentional? If it's intentional, what workaround should I use to add the desired information to my code? Are there other ways to annotate function arguments that e.g. a lint could pick up?

Edit: OK, it appears I'm asking the wrong question. In java, function arguments can be annotated. How would I do something similar in Rust?

Comment: A concrete type plus a bound doesn't really make sense. The type will either support the trait (in which case you can just accept the trait) or it won't. You can't have one type both implement a trait and not, during the same compilation. Perhaps you can explain more about what you want to do? In which way do you care that you have a `u32`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "annotate function arguments" ? What could you annotate more than the type of the argument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust does have annotations, they can be applied to items like `struct`s or `fn`s or `mod`s:

```
#[test]
fn what() {}
```

However, if you use your own:

```
#[my_attr]
fn what() {}
```

You get an error:

```
error: The attribute `my_attr` is currently unknown to the the compiler and may have meaning added to it in the future
help: add #![feature(custom_attribute)] to the crate attributes to enable
```

You also cannot add annotations to an argument:

```
fn what(#[my_attr] a: u8) {}
```

Has the error

```
error: unexpected token: `#`
```

All that being said, I agree with [Levans' sentiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812052/how-can-i-add-a-marker-to-a-concrete-type#comment45903078_28812052) - use types to encode information.

The most common argument annotation I know of in Java is `@Nullable`. In Rust, this has standard library support, not relying on external metadata. You use a special type to indicate that a value can be not present - `Option`:

```
fn what(a: Option<u8>) {}
```

You can also build your own types to indicate semantics. Maybe you have an application that deals with distances? Create a type that represents that:

```
struct Meters(i32);
```